# why is juxt named after juxtaposition?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, function-composition

Why is Clojure's [juxt](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt) named after juxtaposition? I don't see what is being juxtaposed. This is in contrast to `partial` and `comp` which have intuitive naming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I see it now. Each of the functions is evaluated with the same argument and saved for comparison, i.e. juxtaposition.
From the [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt):

```
((juxt a b c) x) => [(a x) (b x) (c x)]
```